# How to use pdfjam as a library in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking for a Library in python to take for example 3 individual pdf and planned them up together, so I found out this one "pdfjam" but I think is just as sheel. Is there any way where I can use it as a Library?

Sorry guys I'm new with python.

Thanks
Neto

Answer (score 0):

I Guess you can PDFknife which makes use of pdfjam under the hood
https://pypi.org/project/PDFknife/

```
pip install PDFknife
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I have tried to find the documentation to see how to use it, but I didn't find it. Do you know where I could find it?

Comment: That's surprising. I could find this git repo https://github.com/sciunto-org/PDFknife which consists of the bundled libs. Hope you find merge.py to do the job for you